# Polars get grouped rows where column value is maximum

Tags: python, python-polars

So consider this snippet

```py
import polars as pl

df = pl.DataFrame({'class': ['a', 'a', 'b', 'b'], 'name': ['Ron', 'Jon', 'Don', 'Von'], 'score': [0.2, 0.5, 0.3, 0.4]})
df.groupby('class').agg([pl.col('score').max()])
```

This gives me:

```
class score
  b     0.4
  a     0.5
```

But I want the entire row of the group that corresponded to the maximum score. I can do a join with the original dataframe like

```
sdf = df.groupby('class').agg([pl.col('score').max()])
sdf.join(df, on=['class', 'score'])
```

To get

```
class  score  name
  a     0.5    Jon
  b     0.4    Von
```

Is there any way to avoid the join and include the name column as part of the groupby aggregation?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use a [`sort_by`](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/api/polars.Expr.sort_by.html) expression to sort your observations in each group by score, and then use the [`last`](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/api/polars.Expr.last.html) expression to take the last observation.

For example, to take all columns:

```py
df.groupby('class').agg([
    pl.all().sort_by('score').last(),
])
```

```
shape: (2, 3)
┌───────┬──────┬───────┐
│ class ┆ name ┆ score │
│ ---   ┆ ---  ┆ ---   │
│ str   ┆ str  ┆ f64   │
╞═══════╪══════╪═══════╡
│ a     ┆ Jon  ┆ 0.5   │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ b     ┆ Von  ┆ 0.4   │
└───────┴──────┴───────┘
```

##### Edit: using `over`

If you have more than one observation that is the `max`, another easy way to get all rows is to use `over`.

For example, if your data has two students in class `b` ('Von' and 'Yvonne') who tied for highest score:

```py
df = pl.DataFrame(
    {
        "class": ["a", "a", "b", "b", "b"],
        "name": ["Ron", "Jon", "Don", "Von", "Yvonne"],
        "score": [0.2, 0.5, 0.3, 0.4, 0.4],
    }
)
df
```

```
shape: (5, 3)
┌───────┬────────┬───────┐
│ class ┆ name   ┆ score │
│ ---   ┆ ---    ┆ ---   │
│ str   ┆ str    ┆ f64   │
╞═══════╪════════╪═══════╡
│ a     ┆ Ron    ┆ 0.2   │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ a     ┆ Jon    ┆ 0.5   │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ b     ┆ Don    ┆ 0.3   │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ b     ┆ Von    ┆ 0.4   │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ b     ┆ Yvonne ┆ 0.4   │
└───────┴────────┴───────┘
```

```py
df.filter(pl.col('score') == pl.col('score').max().over('class'))
```

```
shape: (3, 3)
┌───────┬────────┬───────┐
│ class ┆ name   ┆ score │
│ ---   ┆ ---    ┆ ---   │
│ str   ┆ str    ┆ f64   │
╞═══════╪════════╪═══════╡
│ a     ┆ Jon    ┆ 0.5   │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ b     ┆ Von    ┆ 0.4   │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ b     ┆ Yvonne ┆ 0.4   │
└───────┴────────┴───────┘
```